# POST an object containing array with Angular and Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working on a project that uses **Angular** for the front-end and **Java 1.8** for the back-end with **Springboot**, which is basically a simulator of builds for RPG characters (with the basic stats like health points, mana points, etc ...).

Posting a character was fine with its name, statistics.

But I'm trying to add items to the character and that's where my problem is.

Here's my 
[POST mapping in my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTC0H.png)

Here's the [model class for Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVB4m.png) with its getters and setters (the get/set for the Items is also a list)

And here's how it is on my Angular project

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs3NF.png) , [the methods in my formCharacter component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8phZ3.png), [my formCharacter Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60tcf.png) and finaly the [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAnnD.png) where you chose an item.

And when I submit my form I get this error " **JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token** "

I'm sorry for the wall of text and thanks in advance if anyone has an idea on how to solve this problem.

I'm guessing it's the array of items in my Character's Object that's causing the problem of serialization?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please ask question posting code snippets not code snapshots. This makes it easier for other users to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `JSON` is the actual problem. `JSON` cannot be deserialized by default into a `Collection` because it's not actually a `JSON Array`.

Be sure that the json should be like this `{...}` and in case of multiple elements it should be like -`[{...},{...}]` . for example -

```
{
  "characterName": "lower",
   "healthPoints":"323",
    ...
  "items": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: So as you said, the json was the problem and It was simply the fact that my array wasn't initialized in my angular model.